# Pass dynamic formControl value in template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

How can i pass the exact text area value when the button is clicked?

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="simulationForm">
     <div  formArrayName="answer_key"  *ngFor="let other of simulationForm.get('answer_key').controls; let i = index" class="form-group">

          <div [formGroupName]="i" class="mat-form-field--inline">
                    {{i + 1}}.
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <textarea matInput placeholder="Sentence" id="sentence" formControlName="sentence" readonly="true"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" (click)="openDialog()">Add</button>
                </div>  
          </div>
</form>
```

Wanted to pass the sentence value of each row when each of the button is clicked.

something like,

```
(click)="openDialog(simulationForm.get('sentence').value)"
```

Or

```
(click)="openDialog(simulationForm.get('answer_key').controls['sentence'].value)"
```

Comment: How that you use form control like this: formControlName="sentence". Do you have a form group?

Comment: yes, have updated the question

Comment: If you are using reactive form you don't need to pass the value as a parametor to openDialog method. You can get the value inside your .ts file: this.simulationForm.controls['sentence'].value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(click)="openDialog(i)"

openDialog(index:number)
{
   const text=(simulationForm.get('answer_key') as FormArray)
       .at(index).get('sentence').value

   //or 
   const text=(simulationForm.get('answer_key') as FormArray)
       .at(index).value.sentence

   //I'm not sure about
   const text=simulationForm.value.answer_key[index].sentence


}
```

Comment: Worked well, i didn't think of the index in html.